# Confirmação de compartilhamento do facebook com a API para WEB

Tags: php, api, facebook

Tenho um código em php com um botão do facebook, ao clicar a pessoa compartilha o conteúdo, entretanto, no meu site tem um contador (regressivo), cada vez que alguém compartilhar, retira 1 do contador. O botão foi gerado e está funcional, gostaria de saber se o facebook retorna a confirmação de compartilhamento pela API para eu descontar no contador...

Comment: O que você está usando? Se você usou o share button, aparentemente não tem como https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/, ele até conta, mas não retorna nada(não tem um parametro tipo callback funcation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução, mas não é usando o share button e sim a api,o response só disparado quando o usuário da o compartilhar de fato

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Share Dialog</h1>
</div>

<p>Click the button below to trigger a Share Dialog</p>

<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>

<p style="margin-top: 50px">
  <hr />
  <a class="btn btn-small"  href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog">Share Dialog Documentation</a>
</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){


       if(response.post_id !== 'undefined'){
           alert('foi postado');
       }


  });
}
</script>
```

[Aqui](http://www.fbrell.com/saved/2779dc018c325d85d650a3b723239650) você pode testar o código
[Aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) você tem mais info da api

Aqui esta o load que você precisa colocar para usar a sdk do facebook

```
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Ainda para o SDK você precisa Criar um Facebook App, tem um tutorial [aqui](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/pt/articles/203645706-Criar-um-Facebook-App-ID-App-Secret)

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou